# Nested form validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

Models :

```
Names - belongs_to People
People - has_many names
```

View:

```
= form_for @people do |f|
  .blkfr
    = f.fields_for :names do |f_name|
        = f_name.text_field :name
```

Controller:

```
# People controller
def update
  #find people
  if @people.update_attributes(params[:people])
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated people"
    respond_with @people
  else
    flash[:alert] = "There was an error updating people"
    respond_with @people
  end
end
```

Error:

```
Template is missing

Missing template people/edit, application/edit blah blah
```

I do not have a template for the people's edit method. The route I'm currently hitting is:

```
.../people/1/names
```

My question is how do I tell rails to jump back to the same view (names index page), but return the errors for the @people object without receiving that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have edit template, then specify which template you want to render in your controller.

```
:render => :index
```

Comment: That will render the people's index, and not the names index.

Comment: you can render any template that is in your application

:render => 'people/names/index'